# Contour integral going to zero on a limit

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I've been asked to prove the following;

$$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}\int_{C_R} \frac{z^2 + 8z + 42}{(z^2+4)(z^2-4z+5)}dz=0$$

Given that $C_R$ is a circle of radius $R$ centered at $0$.

I thought the easiest way to prove this would be using the fact that;

$$|\int_C f(z)dz| \le ML$$

Where $M$ is the upper boundary of the integral, and $L$ is the arc length.

Firstly, I noted;
$$|\frac{z^2 + 8z + 42}{(z^2+4)(z^2-4z+5)}| \le \frac{|z^2 + 8z + 42|}{|(z^2+4)(z^2-4z+5)|}$$
And then that;
$$|z^2 + 8z + 42| \le |z|^2 + 8|z| +42 = |R^2 e^{2i\theta}| + 8|Re^{i\theta}|+42 = R^2 + 8R + 42$$
$$|(z^2+4)(z^2-4z+5)| = |z^4 -4z^3 +9z^2-16z+20| \ge||z|^4 -4|z|^3 +9|z|^2-16|z|+20|$$
$$=|R^4 -4R^3 +9R^2-16R+20| = R^4 -4R^3 +9R^2-16R+20$$

Then, I have the following;
$$|\frac{z^2 + 8z + 42}{(z^2+4)(z^2-4z+5)}| \le \frac{R^2 + 8R + 42}{R^4 -4R^3 +9R^2-16R+20} = M$$

Now, it's fairly obvious that the limit of $M$ will go to zero as $R$ approaches $\infty$, so is it appropriate to conclude the following??
$$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} |\int_{C_R} \frac{z^2 + 8z + 42}{(z^2+4)(z^2-4z+5)}dz| \le \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} ML = 0$$
Thus, is it appropriate to say that as the maximum value the function can take is zero, that the entire integral is equal to zero??

Further, we've been asked to use this to show that the same integral over the contour $C$, where $C$ is a circle of radius 5, centre 2, is also equal to zero. Is it appropriate to say that what I've determined will hold for a circle of any given radius, regardless of the point at which it is centered, so that the statement is true??

Any help would be fantastic!!

Comment: For the second part of the problem,t he integral of the function will be the $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of the function at at the poles contained in the circle of radius 5, center 2 (the places where the denominator is 0). This is the Residue Theorem. So you just have to show that the sum of the residues is 0.

Comment: Your work for the limit case looks ok. You could also use the reside theorem there. What's important is not that the limit of $M$ goes to $0$ but that limit of $ML$ goes to 0.

Comment: We haven't done any work with residues yet, so I'm a bit unsure as to how to use them.

In my limit work, would it be stronger to just calculate the limit of $ML$, as $L$ should just be equal to $2\pi R$, which still means the limit goes to zero??

Comment: Correct. That's what your proof should rely on. It's not good enough to show that the limit of $M$ goes to 0 because the limit of $L$ goes to infinity. I think the second part of the problem can be done in the following way:show that the circle of radius $5$ centered around 2 contains all the points at which the function is not defined. Then, if $R$ is large enough, integral of the function on the circle centered at $0$ with radius $R$ and the circle of radius $5$ centered at 2 will be the same because the function will be analytic in the region in between them. Now, apply the limit.